# See how many orders he has on his profile page. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, python-3.9

When I enter my user profile page, I want it to see the total number of orders until today. i tried aggregate and annonate but it's not work. I hope so i use filter method but i don't know how to do it.

Orders count = adet in model

I added ""if siparis.bayi_id == user.id"" so that the user entering can take action on his  orders.
**Temp** Html

```
                                {% for siparis in siparis %}
                                    {% if siparis.bayi_id == user.id %}

                          
                                            <strong>{{ a }}</strong><br><small>Siparişler Toplamı</small>


                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
```

**Model** Siparis means order

```
class Siparis(models.Model):
bayi = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name='bayi', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bayi',limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "BayiGrubu"})
urun = models.ForeignKey(Urun, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
adet = models.IntegerField()
tarih = models.DateTimeField()
status = models.BooleanField()

@property
def miktar(self):
    return (self.adet * self.urun.fiyat)

@property
def fiyat(self):
    return self.urun.fiyat

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Bayi Sipariş'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Bayi Siparişleri'
```

**views**

```
def bayi_bayidetay(request):

siparis = Siparis.objects.all()
urunler = Urun.objects.all()
bayiler = bayi_bilgi.objects.all()

a = Siparis.objects.aggregate(Sum("adet"))
return render(request,'bayi/bayi_detay.html',{'bayiler':bayiler,'siparis':siparis,'urunler':urunler, 'a': a})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add filter after a, like this:

```
a = Siparis.objects.filter(bayi=request.user).aggregate(Sum("adet"))
```

Comment: not working django said 'dict' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Sorry is my mistake, place try this, it can my you get the oder who enter user profile page:
a = Siparis.objects.filter(bayi=request.user).aggregate(Sum("adet"))